# How to populate the nested object id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my schema, I want to join the address in ScheduleSchema to addressDetails in CustomerSchema to list the all address details in a table, how to achieve this?

```
const CustomerSchema = new Schema(
  {
    addressDetails: [
      {
        block: {
          type: String,
        },

        building_number: {
          type: String,
        },

        is_default: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
        },
      },
    ],

  },


const SheduleSchema = new Schema(
    {
        customer: {
            type: ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: "Customer",
        },
        address: {
            type: ObjectId
        },
        week: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    schemaOptions
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must to use `ref` and populate for address key check the [documnetation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), and add this property to the Schemas like this :

```
const SheduleSchema = new Schema(
    {
        customer: {
            type: ObjectId,
            required: true,
            ref: "Customer",
        },
        address: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Customer",
        },
        week: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    schemaOptions
);
```

use populate for get all addresses wit details

```
await SheduleSchema.find().populate({
  path : "address"
})
```